# Do I need to regulate the output of a forward converter?

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, feedback, isolated

I'd like to know if a forward converter will maintain a nominal output on the secondary side. For example if I wind a powdered iron toroidal core with 1:10 turns ratio, the 1 being the primary, and I'm not mentioning the winding that leads back to the power source (the winding that makes it a forward converter), and I input 24 volts on the primary side, will I get 240v nominal in the secondary side without needing any kind of regulation or optocoupler feedback methods?

I ask because forward converters are said to function like low frequency transformers meaning they don't store energy in the core but just transfer it. I'm switching the forward converter at 20 kHz.

So may I please get confirmation of this or I might be completely wrong?

Comment: depends how accurate you need the output voltage to be

Comment: It doesn't have to be accurate, I expect some ripple, but I just need to know if I smooth it out with a big cap, I won't need an optocoupler to adjust the duty cycle. I just want to know if it will work like low frequency transformers

Comment: Depends. Are you always in CCM then with fixed input voltage and duty cycle your output voltage should remain basically the same.

Comment: You'll need more than a 1:10 ratio to cover losses in the converter. Forwards aren't particularly efficient. Also any input voltage variation will directly couple to the output. Feedback and duty cycle control protects you against both input and output variations, as well as things like thermal drift. Generally speaking, an unregulated switcher isn't the best idea. SInce you're boosting from 24 to 240V, why not consider a regulated flyback converter?

Comment: I'm using a 24v battery, so while the battery is at this nominal voltage, I should get 10 times on the output without regulation right?

Comment: It will be less than 10x due to losses. But yes, it will be a pseudo-transformer, with the output of the converter free to move about as input and load changes. The intermediate bus converter approach for small DC/DC converters uses this unregulated approach to divide a DC bus by a specific ratio (48V to 12V, for example) to feed downstream regulated DC/DC converters.

Comment: Cool, so I won't get a constantly increasing output voltage like with an unregulated flyback converter

Comment: See winny's comment. There will be some variation in the output until the converter crosses from DCM into CCM (which will depend on your specific design parameters). Once in CCM the voltage will be less variable.

Comment: I apologize for the dumb questions but the tertiary winding attached right back to the power source, doesn't it mean regardless of the CCM or DCM there will always be a one to ten ratio between input and output because of zero Voltage spikes? Ignoring losses

Comment: Murphy's Law of Regulation - without control, everything will vary a bit more than you expect, or need.

Comment: Re 'regardless of ..." --> No. If you input does not "know" what the output is doing then in DCM the duty cycle can be varied arbitrarily.youbget say 100v pulses but duration between then may be 1 ms or 2 s or ...

Answer (score 1):

yes, it will work like that, giving an approximately 10:1 step-up ratio.

The step-up will be reduced by losses in the switches and the rectifiers, transformer resistance etc...

If you use synchronous rectification it will be even more like a DC transformer, now also capable of stepping a 240V input on the high side down to 24 on the low side.